# I'd like to add a button under the "Add to Cart" button which says "Buy on Amazon" and links to my Amazon product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm hoping for some "additional CSS" I can add to my WordPress customization to get this extra button on my product page!

Comment: This is woocommerce!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy this code to your `functions.php` and you will add a button under Add to Cart Button.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'content_after_addtocart_button' ); 

function content_after_addtocart_button() { 
    echo '<div class="content-section"><br><br><a href="https://www.google.com/"><input id="amazonBtn" type="button" value="Buy on Amazon"/></a></div>'; 
}
```

Change the Google link for your Amazon link.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! Only issue is the "Buy on Amazon" button appears slightly lower but side by side with the "Add to Cart" button... It should be underneath it. Can you help?

Comment: if you show me your site, I cannot help you without seeing the problem.

Comment: Very early days and a lot of work to do, but here is the typical product page: https://thebiogonation.com/product/reusable-rice-husk-coffee-cup

Comment: I just edited the code, I added a on more <br>, it works now, check it out.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Is there a way to make the two buttons the same size? The Amazon one is slightly longer I notice

Comment: You can add an ID to the button (code on answer updated) and then add the following CSS: #amazonBtn {
    width: 29%;
    padding-left: 2%;
}

Comment: Done! And if I want the link to open in a new tab for the Amazon button?

Comment: Also - how could I make both the add to cart and amazon button the same size as the purple stripe "buy now" button above them?

Comment: Search for: open link another tab html. As for the last question, using CSS if you don't know anything about it, find a tutorial, but try to show your attempts.